# Development in codeigniter whit 2 servers

Tags: php, codeigniter

currently i'm developing a Webapplication with php/codeigniter and have only one system (live). For future development i want some kind of environment to make changes at the system and only deploy if im finish.

How i used to build a live/development-system? Currently the app is running on a shared-hosting system.

One idea a have:

- 2 Domains (dev.app.yxz and app.yxz)
- 2 Folder on the hosting-system (complete duplicate)
- 2 Databases

So i can develop and test at the Test-System.

But how i can do the live-deployment? E.g. define which of the files changed?

Edit: because i only have a shared-hosting. I cant install svn or git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use source code management system like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: because i only have a shared-hosting: I cant install svn or git :(